# How can i get the console log of the current website opened in a iframe or page using a chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

How can i get the console logs of the current website opened in a iframe or page using a chrome extensions, i am using chrome debugger protocol for that but i am able to figure the logs

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  console.log("tabs--->", tabs);
  console.log("tabs[0].id", tabs[0].id);

  chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabs[0].id }, "1.1", () => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log("runtime.lastError", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Debugger attached");
  });

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabs[0].id }, "Console.enable", () => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log("runtime.lastError", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Log enabled and result");
  });

  const config = {
    source: "javascript",
    level: "log",
    text: "console.log('hello world')",
  };

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabs[0].id }, "Console.ConsoleMessage", config, () => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log("runtime.lastError", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Log enabled and result");
  });
});
```

I have tried this above code it throws an error `Console.ConsoleMessage` not found

Comment: Add chrome.debugger.onEvent listener then send `Console.enable` command and your listener will be called many times with Console.messageAdded event that contains the message.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can i get the logs whis is present on devtools ?

Comment: @wOxxOm implementating part i am not able to understand , please give some examples

Comment: @wOxxOm https://pastebin.com/3JQQW8qb i  tried this it is not working

Comment: @wOxxOm it is continously printing something please help

Comment: Try adding the listener first as suggested in my comment, then send the command. You can find more examples in google search for chrome.debugger.onEvent. Also, you should look at the listener's third parameter, not the second.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
`column: 11
level: "log"
line: 28
source: "console-api"
text: "params [object Object]"
`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3R7KnKiZ @wOxxOm can you please check what am i doing wrong

Comment: @wOxxOm  i think you checked the the earlier one link, this is current one https://pastebin.com/3R7KnKiZ, thanks <3

Comment: @wOxxOm if you can edit the code that would help a lot , please

Comment: Actually, the documentation says `Console` is deprecated and instead [Log](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log/) should be used, so try that.

Comment: okay  @wOxxOm thanks a lot <3

Comment: `Log` uses a different parameter: `entry` instead of `message`.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the logs

```
chrome.debugger.getTargets((result) => console.log(result) )
```

Here we are adding a event listener

```
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
```

chrome.tabs.query give you the current tab
To enable the logs we have to sendCommand of Log.enable

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  // you can even attach tabId or targetId 
  chrome.debugger.attach(
    { targetId: "FC33D8084B688E98F5929B90326E3A27" },
    "1.3",
    () => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log("runtime.lastError", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Debugger attached");
    }
  );
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
    { targetId: "FC33D8084B688E98F5929B90326E3A27" },
    "Log.enable",
    () => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log("runtime.lastError", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Log enabled and result");
    }
  );
});

function onEvent(debuggeeId, message, params) {
 // Here you can get the logs
  console.log("params", params);
}
```